# Session class with dependency injection

Tags: php, session, dependency-injection

I followed a tut to move the session to database storage, it works as expected however it creates a new instance of the database class which i would prefer not to happen, i can solve this by injection the object.

The reason for my question is that in the session class there is a close method which closes the database connection that the class instantiates.

If i change the class to inject the database object instead will the close the connection globally? If it will then how can i get around that happening as its my understanding that the close method is required.

For reference, here is the tutorial so you can see what i mean.

http://culttt.com/2013/02/04/how-to-save-php-sessions-to-a-database/

Comment: It will close that particular connection. All other connections that aren't explicitly closed will close after a certain period of time. But yes, it will close it globally, so if you're using that certain connection somewhere else it will be unavailable.

Comment: Okay would i be able to get around that? Say, if i was to just return true but not close the connection, would that be bad practice? possible side effects?

Comment: Since you're moving the session to a db, you're obviously serializing the data. There's no real point to serialize an open connection as it may not exist when you unserialize the data. So it's a pretty weird circumstance you got here. You do need to close the connection but at the same time that connection may be used elsewhere.

Comment: The reason for my weird case is smarty, well not directly, Because the website requires a lot of database access i used the database class to extend smarty. Im thinking that decision might have bitten me now.

Basically im trying to avoid every user having two concurrent database connections as they will soon mount up.

I think i will have to go back to the drawing board on this one and rethink the pattern.

Comment: Before you do that, ask around a bit more. I'm not exactly an expert at this thing and there may be a way to workaround this issue.

Comment: I wont make any changes until im sure, im going to look over some design patterns and try to work out how they would implement my particular case.